# Run nightwatch without terminal, through my app?

Tags: node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js

I'm doing tests with nightwatch, but all of them are executed through the terminal, I would like to know if I can execute tasks through my app, without having to use the terminate, ie be inside the application and click on a button and execute A task done with nightwatch.

This is possible?

Comment: Mobile or wep app, please ?

Comment: @BaoTran web app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible:-

```
var nightwatch = require('nightwatch');
var argv = {
  config : ‘./nightwatch.json’,
  // ... other settings that you would have supplied if run through cli
};
var done = function() {}; // your callback function
var settings = {};

nightwatch.runner(argv, done, settings);
```

For more details, follow this discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nightwatchjs/1DTmaer3zG8)